# Firebase Firestore get all Docs is empty in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all sub docs and collections from the collection.

Database structure:

[image]

Code Snippet:

```
_firestore.collection("messages").get().then((querySnapshot) => {getdata(querySnapshot)});
```

But `querySnapshot.docs.length` is always zero.
How can I try to get all data from collection?

Comment: Please provide sample codes so that the community would be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hrmmm what does your current doc query look like?

The id of your documents are a bit confusing, but I'd assume the standard query should work.

**NOTE** : Using sequential keys/numbers as document and collections ID's is **dangerous** and will give you a lot of problems later down the line. If you're not generating unique-ids yourself, let Firestore do it for you. [Firebase - best practices](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

E.g.

To listen to the changes of the `messages/2/1` collection:

```
 final snapshotStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('messages/2/1')
        .snapshots()
        .asBroadcastStream();
```

This returns a stream which contains a snapshot of each of the documents in there that will be updated in 'real-time'. The `.asBroadCastStream()` ensures that you can register multiple listeners to that stream. (Looks like you're using this as some sort of chat feature?)

A little extra, one way to access all the documents within the stream:

```
 await for (final streamSnapshot in snapshotStream) {
          final documentsList = streamSnapshot.docs;
          /// Do something with documentsList
 }
```

Let me know how it goes, good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just know my think is wrong.